# How can I make a button open a specific page in PDF file which is on assets in android studio?

Tags: android

**i have a PDF file in assets in my android app. I want to use buttons to open at specific pages in the PDF because it is too long to scroll **

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: How you are loading PDF files? Are you using [AndroidPDFViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

Comment: Ya I am using GitHub android pdf viewer to load file..@MrinmoyMk..please help me with code if u can

Comment: I am using GitHub Android pdf viewer..@Cristi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you told you are using [AndroidPDFViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer). So just use the below code for it. Also I assume you have already created a button for this

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button); 
PdfView pdfView = findViewById(r.id.pdfView);
//other parts

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pdfView.jumpTo(your_pageno);//this line helps to jump to any page of the pdf
        }
    });
```

**EDIT**

If you have the button and the pdfView in different activity then you can use it as

- Inside MainActivty

  ```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), pdfActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("pageno", 5); // add this to pass the page number
           startActivity(intent);
       }
   });
  ```
- Inside pdfActivity

  ```
  pdfView = findViewById(R.id.mypdf);
  pdfView.fromAsset("SAMPLE_FILE.pdf")
       .defaultPage(getIntent().getIntExtra("pageno",0)) // this is used to scroll to the page required
       .enableAnnotationRendering(true)
       .scrollHandle(new DefaultScrollHandle(this))
       .load();
  ```

Comment: Thanks for ur response@MrinmoyMk .I have tried it..but it is showing error. I also tried intent from main activity( with button) to pdfview activity and then  jumping to the page no. Its still not working out..

Comment: Can you post your codes, how you are loading the PDF. Actually, I personally use this library to display PDF and use the above `jumpTo()` method to go to any pages. If you use it correctly it will surely work. Can you also post what is the error

Comment: i have posted the codes below..please have a look..@MrinmoyMk

Comment: I think you must post the code in your question section, not as an answer. Also you must have the `pdfView,jumpTo();` inside your `class pdfActivity` not in different class

Comment: @MrinmoyMk..I am getting an error at the last line of the pdfActivity. The error says [ jumpTo(int) in PDFView cannot be applied to (java.lang.string) ]. Since i m new to android n stakeoverflow so i m finding difficulties. thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @MrinmoyMk..Bro i have tried as u have posted after editing. the programme runs as usual with the button opening at 1st page only. The code line `(getIntent().getStringExtra("pageno"))` is highlighted in AndroidStudio, may be  something wrong. couldnot find it out.

Comment: Could you post the error, of AndroidStudio highlight

Comment: @MrinmoyMk..Error is`Inspection Info: This inspection analyse method control and data flow to report possible conditions that are always true or false, expressions whose value is statically proven to be constant and situations that can lead to nullability contract violations. Variables, method parameters and return vales marked as @Nullable or NotNull are treated as nullable or not-null respectively and used during the analysis to check nullability contracts, eg. report NullPointerException errors might be produced.  The inspection can be configured to use custom @Nullable@NotNull annotations`

Comment: I have fixed the error. Now it must work as this time I have tested personally in my existing project. If it helps please accept it as answer

Comment: yeah it works..thank you bros for your efforts..@Manash & @MrinmoyMk

Comment: Glad to know that it worked. Feel free to ask any more doubt if you have. Also please accept this answer as it fixed your issue